# ShellScript in a Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I've written the following makefile:

```
# make the iMe program
#

SDIR=src
IDIR=include
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
EDIR=bin

LIBS=-lrt -lpthread

_DEPS = 1.h 2.h 3.h 4.h 5.h 6.h 7.h 8.h 9.h 10.h 11.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = 1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o 5.o 6.o 7.o 8.o 9.o 10.o 11.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    gcc -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -O3

$(EDIR)/iMe: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# Clean 

clean:
    -rm -f ./$(ODIR)/* $(OBJ) ./$(EDIR)/*

# Backup 

backup:
    tar -czvf backup_iMe_`date +%d-%m-%Y`.tar.gz *


# Run the program with first cenario
run_first:
./$(EDIR)/iMe ./tests/in/cenario1 ./tests/out/cenario1 -l cenario1.log -t 1000

#Run the program with second cenario
run_second:
./$(EDIR)/iMe ./tests/in/cenario2 ./tests/out/cenario2 -l cenario2.log -t 1000
```

Although everything runs perfectly, i want to separate the run parts to a different file, called tests.sh, and then call them in the makefile.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run the program with first cenario
run_first:
./bin/iMe ./tests/in/cenario1 ./tests/out/cenario1 -l cenario1.log -t 1000

#Run the program with second cenario
run_second:
./bin/iMe ./tests/in/cenario2 ./tests/out/cenario2 -l cenario2.log -t 1000
```

However this doesn't work, because i don't know how to call it in the makefile... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I just did a google for "launch shell script from Make" and I ended up here http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/159963-how-run-shell-script-through-makefile.html

Comment: I've tried that already @robert... every time i try to run it, i get this error `make: execvp: ./tests.sh: Permission denied`. I even did `chmod 666 tests.sh`

Comment: You could just invoke the tests.sh as long as it has executable permission directly from the other makefile. Just include `tests.sh` in the line after your backup. Since this invokes this from a different process, the reference to `./` might be lost. It would be better to specify the directory name instead of ./.

Comment: @DiogoCarou . Run this command - `chmod +x tests.sh` in your shell and it should run.

Comment: `666` permissions does not include the execute permission bit which you need to run a script. You want `755` or `750` or similar for an executable script.

Comment: thanks @rahul! Turns out it was a permission issue!

Comment: You need the first digit of your chmod to be 7 to set the executable bit. Or you could just do u+x

Comment: @rahul i'm getting a different problem now! Every time i run it, no matter if i choose the first or the second option, it always runs the one that comes last in the code...

Comment: @DiogoCarou . I don't see any conditional operators there. What is the input value based on which you switch? From what i can see, both of them will be excuted, which makes you think that only the second one is executed.

Comment: @rahul yes that's what i was going to say... how can i change it so only the desired one is executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the choice as an argument to the `tests.sh` script. Here is the content of makefile

```
# make the iMe program
#

SDIR=src
IDIR=include
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
EDIR=bin

LIBS=-lrt -lpthread

_DEPS = 1.h 2.h 3.h 4.h 5.h 6.h 7.h 8.h 9.h 10.h 11.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = 1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o 5.o 6.o 7.o 8.o 9.o 10.o 11.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    gcc -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -O3

$(EDIR)/iMe: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# Clean 

clean:
    -rm -f ./$(ODIR)/* $(OBJ) ./$(EDIR)/*

# Backup 

backup:
    tar -czvf backup_iMe_`date +%d-%m-%Y`.tar.gz *


./tests.sh 1
#./tests.sh 2
```

Then here is the content of `tests.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run the program with first scenario
scenario=$1
if [ $1 -eq 1 ]
then
./bin/iMe ./tests/in/cenario1 ./tests/out/cenario1 -l cenario1.log -t 1000
elif [ $1 -eq 2 ]
then
#Run the program with second scenario
#run_second:
./bin/iMe ./tests/in/cenario2 ./tests/out/cenario2 -l cenario2.log -t 1000
fi
```